# How can i shorten the decimal of an e value to only 2 digits

Tags: javascript

I want to shorten decimals for large numbers like 1.348526328757346254637e91 to 1.34e91 for  my javascript game that handles very large numbers. How can i do this? Here is the code i want the system in

```
function addClicks(amount) {
 clicks = clicks + amount * multiplier;
 document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

Comment: those numbers are likely to loose a vast amount of precision in javascript

Comment: Did you try [Number.prototype.toExponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) and specify 2 digits?

Comment: Why? What is your goal? What are you doing with the numbers? More details are needed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, I thought that was the point...to _format_ the number as a string.  There are bigger problems here anyway, like floating point precision.  Maybe we should be suggesting BigInt.  `innerHTML` is a string anyway.

Comment: @Wyck - got it. You are on point here.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more of the solution you're looking for, if you like those clicker games. Also, this implementation explicitly does **not round up**, because it's no fun to be declared a centillionaire until you actually are one!

```js
const americanNames = [
  'one', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion', 'quintillion', 'sextillion', 'septillion', 'octillion', 'nonillion',
  'decillion', 'undecillion', 'duodecillion', 'tredecillion', 'quattuordecillion', 'quindecillion', 'sexdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 
  'vigintillion', 'unvigintillion', 'duovigintillion', 'trevigintillion', 'quattuorvigintillion', 'quinvigintillion', 'sexvigintillion', 'septenvigintillion', 'octovigintillion', 'novemvigintillion',
  'trigintillion', 'untrigintillion', 'duotrigintillion', 'tretrigintillion', 'quattuortrigintillion', 'quintrigintillion', 'sextrigintillion', 'septentrigintillion', 'octotrigintillion', 'novemtrigintillion',
  'quadragintillion', 'unquadragintillion', 'duoquadragintillion', 'trequadragintillion', 'quattuorquadragintillion', 'quinquadragintillion', 'sexquadragintillion', 'septenquadragintillion', 'octoquadragintillion', 'novemquadragintillion',
  'quinquagintillion', 'unquinquagintillion', 'duoquinquagintillion', 'trequinquagintillion', 'quattuorquinquagintillion', 'quinquinquagintillion', 'sexquinquagintillion', 'septenquinquagintillion', 'octoquinquagintillion', 'novemquinquagintillion', 
  'sexagintillion', 'unsexagintillion', 'duosexagintillion', 'tresexagintillion', 'quattuorsexagintillion', 'quinsexagintillion', 'sexsexagintillion', 'septsexagintillion', 'octosexagintillion', 'novemsexagintillion',
  'septuagintillion', 'unseptuagintillion', 'duoseptuagintillion', 'treseptuagintillion', 'quattuorseptuagintillion', 'quinseptuagintillion', 'sexseptuagintillion', 'septseptuagintillion', 'octoseptuagintillion', 'novemseptuagintillion',
  'octogintillion', 'unoctogintillion', 'duooctogintillion', 'treoctogintillion', 'quattuoroctogintillion', 'quinoctogintillion', 'sexoctogintillion', 'septoctogintillion', 'octooctogintillion', 'novemoctogintillion',
  'nonagintillion', 'unnonagintillion', 'duononagintillion', 'trenonagintillion', 'quattuornonagintillion', 'quinnonagintillion', 'sexnonagintillion', 'septnonagintillion', 'octononagintillion', 'novemnonagintillion',
  'centillion',
  // Up to you past this point.
];

function formatBigPositiveNumber(n) {
  const str = BigInt(n).toString();
  const len = str.length;
  if (len <= 3) {
    return str;
  } else if (len <= 6) {
    return str.slice(0, len - 3) + ',' + str.slice(-3);
  } else {
    const magnitude = ((len - 1) / 3) | 0;
    const place = 1 + (len + 2) % 3;
    const sig = str.slice(0, 4);
    const name = americanNames[magnitude];
    if (!name) throw new Error('I cannot format that number');
    return sig.substring(0, place) + '.' + sig.substring(place) + ' ' + name
  }
}


//////// TEST CASES

const testCases = [
  [0, '0'],
  [1, '1'],
  [12, '12'],
  [123, '123'],
  [1234, '1,234'],
  [12345, '12,345'],
  [123456, '123,456'],
  [999999, '999,999'],
  [1234567, '1.234 million'],
  [12345678, '12.34 million'],
  [123456789, '123.4 million'],
  [1234567891, '1.234 billion'],
  [999999999, '999.9 million'], // Explicitly does not round up to billion on purpose!
  [1.348526328757346254637e91, '13.48 novemvigintillion'],
];

function fixedWidth(str, n) {
  return (' '.repeat(n) + str).slice(-n);
}

for (let [input, expected] of testCases) {
  const actual = formatBigPositiveNumber(input);
  console.log('\n%s\n%s', fixedWidth(input, 25), fixedWidth(expected, 25));
  console.log('%s', fixedWidth(actual, 25));
}
```

Comment: will this work for pre defined variables im bad at reading code

Comment: @Plazl, yes, of course.  You can even try that yourself.